# Programatically gathering nested object keys from response in Angular

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I am receiving a nested response back from a server in my Angular app.  I need to access the data inside, but there are several responses contained within one parent object.  So far I have been able to drill inside somewhat, but I am having trouble getting in further.

So far I have this code:

```
getPlants(): Observable<any> { 
const headers = { headers: this.headers };
return this.httpClient.get(`${this.requestUrl}, headers);
}
```

This gets the data in question.  Next, I have the function where I am having issues.

```
destructurePlants() {

         this.getPlants().subscribe(data => {
         const plants = Object.keys(data).map(e => data[e]);
         plants.forEach(plant => {
              console.log(plant);
         });
    }
```

The data I am getting back comes back like this.

```
{
     "plantMap": {
          "1": {
               "PLANTTYPE1": {
                    "id": "1",
                    "style": "plantStyle",
                    "styleDesc": "Luxurious green",
                    "codeId": "1"
               },
               "PLANTTYPE2": {
                    "id": "1",
                    "style": "plantStyle2",
                    "styleDesc": "Luxurious red",
                    "codeId": "2"
               },
               "PLANTTYPE3": {
                    "id": "1",
                    "style": "plantStyle3",
                    "styleDesc": "Luxurious succulent",
                    "codeId": "3"
               },
          "2": {
               "TREE1": {
                    "id": "2",
                    "style":"plantStyle",
                    "styleDesc":"Oak",
                    "codeId": "1"
               },
               "TREE2": {
                    "id": "2",
                    "style": "plantStyle2",
                    "styleDesc": "Evergreen",
                    "codeId": "2"
               },
               "TREE3": {
                    "id": "2",
                    "style": "plantStyle3",
                    "styleDesc": "Myrtle",
                    "codeId": "3"
               }
         }
     }
}
```

Ideally, I would like to be able to grab each 1, 2, etc and then drill down further into PLANTTYPE AND TREETYPE objects, etc.

Comment: What final object should look like after parsing the response can you please add final object you need in your question.

Comment: I would like to push each of the Objects under each number 1 or 2 for example into an array, that way I could access them by the number.  So in the future, if I needed the data nested behind 1, 2 or any other number found in the response, I can grab it and use it my HTML templates etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot one closing `}` for your `plantMap["1"]`, beside that, The output of the snippet below is array of plants.

```
"1": {
           "PLANTTYPE1": {
                "id": "1",
                "style": "plantStyle",
                "styleDesc": "Luxurious green",
                "codeId": "1"
           },
           "PLANTTYPE2": {
                "id": "1",
                "style": "plantStyle2",
                "styleDesc": "Luxurious red",
                "codeId": "2"
           },
           "PLANTTYPE3": {
                "id": "1",
                "style": "plantStyle3",
                "styleDesc": "Luxurious succulent",
                "codeId": "3"
           },
      "2": {
```

```js
const data =  {
          "1": {
               "PLANTTYPE1": {
                    "id": "1",
                    "style": "plantStyle",
                    "styleDesc": "Luxurious green",
                    "codeId": "1"
               },
               "PLANTTYPE2": {
                    "id": "1",
                    "style": "plantStyle2",
                    "styleDesc": "Luxurious red",
                    "codeId": "2"
               },
               "PLANTTYPE3": {
                    "id": "1",
                    "style": "plantStyle3",
                    "styleDesc": "Luxurious succulent",
                    "codeId": "3"
               }},
          "2": {
               "TREE1": {
                    "id": "2",
                    "style":"plantStyle",
                    "styleDesc":"Oak",
                    "codeId": "1"
               },
               "TREE2": {
                    "id": "2",
                    "style": "plantStyle2",
                    "styleDesc": "Evergreen",
                    "codeId": "2"
               },
               "TREE3": {
                    "id": "2",
                    "style": "plantStyle3",
                    "styleDesc": "Myrtle",
                    "codeId": "3"
               }
         }
     };
      
let arr = [];
const plants = Object.keys(data).map(e => data[e]);
plants.forEach(plant => {
  const plant_ = Object.keys(plant).map(e => plant[e]);
  arr.push(...plant_);
});
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can (recommanded) use `rxjs` to access your data. The way you do it highly depend on what you want to achieve but here is [a simple example on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-bifrqh?file=index.ts) of how you can do that, and here is the code :

```
import { of } from 'rxjs'; 
import { map, pluck, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';


const data = {
     "plantMap": {
          "1": {
               "PLANTTYPE1": {
                    "id": "1",
                    "style": "plantStyle",
                    "styleDesc": "Luxurious green",
                    "codeId": "1"
               },
               "PLANTTYPE2": {
                    "id": "1",
                    "style": "plantStyle2",
                    "styleDesc": "Luxurious red",
                    "codeId": "2"
               },
               "PLANTTYPE3": {
                    "id": "1",
                    "style": "plantStyle3",
                    "styleDesc": "Luxurious succulent",
                    "codeId": "3"
               },
          },
          "2": {
               "TREE1": {
                    "id": "2",
                    "style":"plantStyle",
                    "styleDesc":"Oak",
                    "codeId": "1"
               },
               "TREE2": {
                    "id": "2",
                    "style": "plantStyle2",
                    "styleDesc": "Evergreen",
                    "codeId": "2"
               },
               "TREE3": {
                    "id": "2",
                    "style": "plantStyle3",
                    "styleDesc": "Myrtle",
                    "codeId": "3"
               }
          }
      }
};

const data$ = of(data);
let plantTypes;
let trees;

data$.pipe(
  pluck('plantMap'),
  tap(obj => {
    plantTypes = obj['1'];
    trees = obj['2'];
  }),
  tap(_ => {
    console.log('plantTypes = ', plantTypes);
    console.log('trees = ', trees);
  })
).subscribe();
```

Here I use `pluck` to select the node I want to target. Pretty simple here since you have only one.

Then I set both segments of data inside constant with `tap` and then display them with another `tap` (could be in the same of course, just an example to show that you can chain method inside the `pipe`).

The last `subscribe()` is just here to trigger the code. It is only triggered when a subscription is made to the observable, either like that of though the `asyncPipe` of angular (which is a must use when you can).

If you want to access you data differently, please explain your context and what you try to achieve and i'll edit my answer :).

Note that **I added a bracket `{` to close the `1` part of your object**, I assumed it should be like this.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far!  So basically, this is going to be a list of 15 or so responses (I only put in 2 for brevity's sake).  I essentially need to sort these out so that each set of data under the number (1, 2, 3 etc) can be referenced by the number and the data can be accessed inside each number.

I will create an interface to help with this since they will have the "id", "style", "styleDesc", and "codeId" properties.

Comment: @user3019183 Ok well you just need to fix the brackets problem. You object is already accessible through `data.plantMap["1"]`. This will return all the plantTypes, 2 will return trees etc..